# How to customize extractCSS in Nuxt 2.x

Tags: nuxt.js

Nuxt 2 allows us to extract all CSS into an external file:

https://v2.nuxt.com/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-build/#extractcss

However, there are some components that I want to exclude because the CSS must exist on initial page load (before JS runs). Is there a way to add exclusion rules to `extractCSS`? I don't see a way to do it OOTB. If not, what are some workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

One workaround is to simply write inline CSS. Inline styles are not extracted by `extractCSS`.